ML2430-HZ1 - Battery Replacement in Tacktick Sailmaster
I am trying to replace the rechargeable Sanyo ML2430-HZ1 batteries (x4) in a sailing computer, as per this tutorial - https://www.instructables.com/Tack-Tick-RaceMaster-Battery-Replacement-33/
As I understand it, the ML2430 (at least the Sanyo one) stopped being produced in 2020, so I need an alternative. While there are some stockists in the USA, I live in New Zealand and shipping lithium batteries here is almost impossible from these stockists, it seems.
There are some ML2430 format batteries available on AliExpress, though none have the ‘HZ1’ connection type.
My current best options, as far as I can tell, are to use a version with the HJ1 connection (looks very similar… though a narrow connection rather than wide) eg -
https://a.aliexpress.com/_mPsph3V
…or use an Cda generic ‘H type’ connector (also very similar, but again narrow) -
https://a.aliexpress.com/_mOYSWIP
Does anyone know if these would work? Specs all the same but mount type different, I think.
Original Sanyo specs here:
https://www.batterybob.com/Battery-Reference/Sanyo-Specs.pdf
And Cda specs here:
https://en.cda-cap.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/01/Bus_Elx_DS_4099_ML_Series_Button-Cell.pdf
Unfortunately neither as cheap as the apparently circa $5 replacements when they were actually being made by Sanyo still!
